Declare Variables in ytt template or use control statements in text templated strings
Looking for a solution to this problem I have. Am a newbie to ytt so pardon my ignorance.
Core issue we have a template file that uses text-templated-string which looks like
keystring:  'initialString: (@= str(data.values.rootelem.childelem) @)'

Childelem is optional and hence would like a way to check its presence and default if  not similar to this
key: #@ data.values.rootelem.childelem if hasattr(data.values.rootelem, "childelem")  else "default"

So how to merge the two functionality and have this line to work
keystring:  'initialString: (@= str(data.values.rootelem.childelem if hasattr(data.values.rootelem, "childelem")  else "default") @)' 

or
keystring:  'initialString: (@= str(key) @)'


You can write a standalone line of Starlark (Pythonish) code just by writing a line by itself starting with the #@ marker.  This can include a variable assignment
#@ key = data.values.rootelem.childelem if hasattr(data.values.rootelem, "childelem")  else "default"

When you need to use the variable, mark the entire value as a template value.  You can use string concatenation to produce the combined value including some string-literal parts and some variable-reference parts.  Again, the template expression looks almost exactly like what you'd write in Python (except the Starlark language does not support f"..." interpolated strings).
keystring: #@ 'initialString: (@= str(' + key + ') @)'
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
#                  literal string         var   literal

